# Adding graphic environment to yocto image

Tags: yocto

I have build a linux image with yocto that has xfce as desktop environment,
But what i actually need is just a terminal and a browser.

Is it possible to remove the desktop environment and just create an application that has two options to open 'terminal' and 'browser' and make my image boots on it directly.

If this is possible would it reduce the image size or not, beacause i am looking for a minimum sie of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove your desktop env then add below line in your `disto.bb` or `local.conf`

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove += "x11 wayland"
```

I dont think without desktop env you cant run browser.
are you using imx6 and vivante graphics ?